# Server optimization for WP on Dreamhost VPS: mod_php + xcache? FCGI?

Tags: php, web-server, vps, dreamhost, fcgi

I'm trying to optimally configure mbird.com, a WP driven site, from use on my new VPS.

On this page: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PS_Optimization - under "WordPress optimization" I see a couple pieces of advice.

1) "If all domains are set to use FCGI or CGI for the PHP mode, you may safely deactivate mod_php in the PS configuration to save a good deal of memory. All modern PHP applications will run fine exclusively on fcgi."

**I currently have mod_php off, running fcgi.**

Then, in VPS -> Configure server, I see:

"Removes mod_php from the Apache web server. This will save a significant amount of memory if your site serves a lot of static content. PHP-intensive sites may benefit more from setting all domains to use mod_php in Manage Domains and enabling a PHP cache."

These seems to be contradictory. One is telling me to turn it off to save memory, the other suggests I can benefit from using it on PHP intensive site. Which would be best for mine?

2) "Please keep in mind that running Super Cache alongside xcache can actually drive memory usage up. It's best to pick either one or the other and use it solely for your caching needs."

**I'm currently not using a plugin-cache (Super Cache), but using xcache.**

However, here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/WordPress_Optimization

The conclusion is: "Ultimately, it seems clear that the supercache + nofcgi version wins out. " **Does that mean, since I'm not using supercache, but xcache, I should use xcache + nofcgi? In other words, mod_php + xcache?**

Sorry, just a little befuddled....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I am having a lot of memory issues on dreamhost and I just got advice from customer support that my PHP instances are taking more memory because I have xCache turned on. I am advised to turn it off.

"if you were to disable xCache you
would be saving a great deal of memory because all your PHP opcode would
not be saved in RAM."

I am also using w3 total cache. both wp-supercache and w3 total cache do not work well with xcache.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation so far as your setup would be FCGI, XCache and
w3 total cache (which do play nicely together). I'm not certain whether
XCache and wp-cache play nice together, but as wp-super-cache is based on
wp-cache I would imagine not.